# Mongodb: how to pass current date filter in aggregate pipeline from javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to get a simple date-filtered aggregation working.

I have documents like:

```
{ 
  "name" : "Article 1",
  "expires" : <some date [type:datetime]> 
},
{ 
  "name" : "Article 1",
  "expires" : <some other date [type:datetime]>
},
...
```

I'm trying to query them with an aggregate pipeline over a **call from javascript**, so my pipeline is passing over as JSON.

I want to get all unexpired documents, but I haven't found a way to use the $$NOW variable that works for me.

```
var pipeline = [
 {'$sort' : {[name] : 1}},
 { "$match": {
    "expires": {"$gt": "$$NOW"}
   }
 }
];

await myGetData(collection, pipeline).then(resp => ...
```

I've also tried variations of $dateFromString without any success. This should be simple, so I assume I'm doing something dumb.

The issue seems to be getting the correct date format into the pipeline JSON. From other stackoverflow questions, it seems that it needs to be a data object for comparison? Not sure how to describe that in the JSON though.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Is `expires` a real datetime or a string?

Comment: H, I've updated the question. The Expires field in the mongodb document is a datetime.